# Function definition in clojure

Tags: clojure

Can anyone explain me this function definition line of clojure

```
 (defn insert [{:keys [el left right] :as tree} value] 
      (**something**))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is argument destructuring in Clojure. You can read more about it here: https://gist.github.com/john2x/e1dca953548bfdfb9844

`{:keys [el left right]}` assumes the first argument (we'll call it `arg`) is a map and binds `(:el arg)` to `el`, `(:left arg)` to `left` and `(:right arg)` to `right` for the scope of the function.

`{:keys [.. .. ..]} :as tree}` binds `arg` to `tree`.

Then `value` is handled normally, without any desctructuring.

Answer (score 3):

The insert function is using destructuring for maps, retrieving values from keys. I think the below would make this clearer:

```
(defn insert [{:keys [el left right] :as tree} value]
      (println (str el " " left " " right))
      (println "-")
      (println tree)
      (println "-")
      (println value)   )


(def mytree  {:el "el" :left "left" :right "right"})

(insert mytree 3)
```

Comment: But why we have  :keys   here? Cant we just pass a deftype and use it

Comment: You could do that or you could also just pass a map, but if your data is just tree-like enough that you want to use this function and you don't want to make it into records then I'm pretty sure defining the function like this leaves it more generic/reusable.